# do not let git merge delete a file

Tags: git, merge

Say I have branch A and B. In A there is some file being deleted. Now A is being merged into B and I want to have this existing in B after merge. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just `git merge` with `--no-commit` and then checkout the deleted file from B again before committing?

Comment: It does commit event with --no-commit option on. Maybe I have some config wrong?

Comment: Hey let's all downvote a question that was explained clearly! *sigh*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If (for whatever reason) `--no-commit` *really* isn't working for you, go ahead and do the merge. Then, do a `git checkout head~ path/to/file`. Then, do a `commit --amend`. This will amend the merge commit to have the deleted file as it was in branch B before the merge.

Answer (score 1):

Something about this doesn't make sense.

The situation you describe is pretty standard for collaborative work; a file may get deleted and when your merge that branch in another branch, its deletion is reflected.

Git is simply relaying the fact that the deletion happened at some point in history, and once you merge two branches together, that fact translates over smoothly (unless there was a conflict on this file).

Upon merge, you are stating that these two branches now contain the same information, and if one branch has information that you don't want conveyed, you must address it, preferably on that branch.

To do this, navigate to the specific commit that removed that file, and execute `git revert` on it.

```
git revert <sha>
```

If that particular revert would have changed any other files around, then perhaps one should discuss why the file was deleted with the other committer in the first place.